# Making a HTML file more interactive

Tags: html

I have a html file and would like to upload it to my server how would I make it so that I would be able to interact with the user?

Comment: Like what? signup or animation?

Comment: @Kluefinapel Most HTML files are designed to interact with the user. Please be more specific what "interact with the user" exactly means.

Comment: By reading your question seems that you have more than one problem: 1) how to upload HTML files on the server, 2) making the content of that HTML file interactive. Would you be able to expand a little bit your question? Maybe add some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to allow for more functionality.
You can add it to a website by using the `<script>` tag

Comment: Please, don't suggest to add javascript before having a good understanding of what the users needs to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, will not happen again.
Hope it will still answer @Kluefinapel 's question

Comment: Hopefully. We will see :)